# Confusion between {..|..} and {...such that..}

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across the following equation in [Mathematics for Machine Learning by Garret Thomas](https://gwthomas.github.io/docs/math4ml.pdf) [page 9]

$$ range(T) = \{w \in W |\ \exists v \in V such \ that \ Tv=w \}$$

I was under the impression that $\{..|..\}$ meant such that. Could some please explain to me what exactly it means in this context?

Comment: The $\mid$ or $:$ notation in set builder notation is used to separate the conditions on the set and where the set is pulling from ($w\in W$ in this instance). When spoken, both $\mid$ and $:$ can said as "such that", but it is a formal part of set builder notation to have a consistent notation across different contexts. Note that the notation is universal: it can be used across languages without any confusion.

Comment: Yes, It means "such that".  The entire statement means "the range of function T is the set of all w in set W **such that** there exist v in set V such that Tv= w".  Presumably T is a function from V to W.  The range of T is the subset of W "such that" T maps some member of V to w.

Comment: range$(T)$ is the set of elements of $W$ such that each, for some element $v$ of $V,$ equals $Tv.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your function is $T\colon V\to W$. Then the codomain of this function is $W$ and the range of $T$ is the subset of all $w\in W$ which are actually realized by the function $T$.

That is, $w\in\textrm{range}(T)$ if and only if there exists an element $v\in V$ with $T(v)=w$. Note that $W=\textrm{range}(T)$ is not necessarily true, it might be that $\textrm{range}(T)\subsetneq W$. Therefore the elements in $\textrm{range}(T)$ need to be characterized by a special property.

So in the notation $\left\{\cdot | \cdot\right\}$ or $\left\{\cdot : \cdot\right\}$, the part after the "$|$" or the "$:$" simply describes the property that an element of $W$ needs to satisfy in order to be contained in this set. Whether you read this as *such that* or *for which* or *with the property that* is your personal decision and a matter of taste.

Answer (score 3):

I read it as 'where' or 'for which'. So I would read you described set as "all w in W, for which, there exists an v in V such that Tv=w".

Comment: Or you could read the "$|$" as "such that" too. The sentence with that phrase twice would be correct, but ugly.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, if you just write that set builder notation out in plain language, with two "such that"s, then it is ambiguous.

But you can remove the ambiguity by putting parentheses into your plain language, like this:

> The set of all $w$ in $W$ such that (there exists $v$ in $V$ such that $Tv=w$).